# Having trouble with leafletProxy, observeEvent and shiny / leaflet application

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

For the last few hours I have been playing with my coding, using forms of if statements, observeEvent and leafletProxy, but I can't seem to get it working. The life table is life expectancy data. It is three columns, COUNTY, male, female. I can't seem to get the radio button to work and it always stays at male.

Basically, I want my leaflet map to give different layouts based on the input of the radio button. Either getting male life expectancy and female, as well as getting the popup.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(tigris)
library(dplyr)

lnd <- counties(state = 'IN', cb = TRUE, resolution = '20m')

#Read life table
life <- read.table("life.txt",sep="\t", header=TRUE)

lnd@data <- left_join(lnd@data, life, by = c('NAME' = 'county'))

popup <- paste0("County name: ", lnd$NAME, "<br>", "Life Expectancy: ", round(lnd$male,2))
popup2 <- paste0("County name: ", lnd$NAME, "<br>", "Life Expectancy: ", round(lnd$female,2))


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(#theme = "bootstrap.css",

titlePanel("Life Exptectancy in Indiana Counties: "),
h3("A Spatial Analysis Project"),
br(),
sidebarLayout(position = "right",

            sidebarPanel(
              tags$b("Life Expectancy in Indiana, U.S.A."),
              hr(),
              radioButtons("gender",     "Gender:",c("Male"="Male","Female"="Female")),

              hr()
            ),
            mainPanel(
              leafletOutput("map")
            )
   )
))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(lnd) %>%
      addPolygons() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron)
  })
  observeEvent (input$gender == "Male", {
    leafletProxy("map", data=lnd) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addPolygons(stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 1, popup = popup)
  })
  observeEvent (input$gender == "Female", {
    leafletProxy("map", data=lnd) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addPolygons(stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 1, popup = popup2)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is a photo of my app[The app remains blue, and keeps the same male data no matter if I click female or male. I know it has to do with something with leafletProxy but cant figure it out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPbds.jpg)

Comment: This is kind of old, but I just stumbled on it. The problem is that you are providing it with same data 'lnd' no matter theinput$gender. You need to create a reactive function that filters the data based on selected gender.

Answer (score 1):

The two `observeEvent` for `input$gender` is creating the problem as only the first  `observeEvent` will get executed. If you change your server using only one `observeEvent` and putting if and else condition inside that it should work. Since I don't have your data `life.txt`, I have produced the life expectancy with some random values.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(tigris)
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(long = rnorm(40) * 2 + 13, lat = rnorm(40) + 48)

#Read life table
life <- read.table("life.txt",sep="\t", header=TRUE)

#lnd@data <- left_join(lnd@data, life, by = c('NAME' = 'county'))
lnd@data <- cbind(lnd@data, male = rnorm(nrow(lnd@data), 50, 10), female = rnorm(nrow(lnd@data), 40, 5))


popup <- paste0("County name: ", lnd$NAME, "<br>", "Life Expectancy: ", round(lnd$male,2))
popup2 <- paste0("County name: ", lnd$NAME, "<br>", "Life Expectancy: ", round(lnd$female,2))


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(#theme = "bootstrap.css",

  titlePanel("Life Exptectancy in Indiana Counties: "),
  h3("A Spatial Analysis Project"),
  br(),
  sidebarLayout(position = "right",

                sidebarPanel(
                  tags$b("Life Expectancy in Indiana, U.S.A."),
                  hr(),
                  radioButtons("gender",     "Gender:",c("Male"="Male","Female"="Female")),

                  hr()
                ),
                mainPanel(
                  leafletOutput("map")
                )
  )
))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(lnd) %>%
      addPolygons() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron)
  })
  observeEvent (input$gender , {
    if(input$gender == "Male"){
      leafletProxy("map", data=lnd) %>%
        clearShapes() %>%
        addPolygons(stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 1, popup = popup) 
    }else
    {
      leafletProxy("map", data=lnd) %>%
        clearShapes() %>%
        addPolygons(stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 1, popup = popup2)
    }

  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I changed the coding, unfortunately it is still giving me a blue map. It seems the data isn't changing between male and female (that might be the underlying issue) because when I click on a census, it continues to give me the Life Expectancy of Male's  no matter if I click the radio button of male or female.

Comment: That's because both the `leafletProxy` is getting the same data that is being plotted as the polygon. The difference in both the maps is that the life expectancy value. If you check that for the same county the value will be different based on the `radioButton` selected.

Comment: I tried again a third time but no matter the radioButton, I will still get Male Life Expectancy Values. I added a image of how the app looks. It just remains blue no matter the gender, and it keeps the same male values. The Life Expectancy table is 3 columns: county name, male value, female value with 92 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a reactive dataset for the user inputs. You are using the same dataset `lnd` in your code.

I don't know how your data is structured and since I don't have your data, I hope it is understood in this example.

```
# Data filtered male
lndMale <- reactive({
      lnd[lnd$gender == input$gender, ]
})  


# Data filtered female
lndFemale <- reactive({
      lnd[lnd$gender == input$gender, ]
})
```

Then you use the reactive dataset where it needs to be.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(lnd) %>%
      addPolygons() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron)
  })
  observeEvent (input$gender == "Male", {
    leafletProxy("map", data=lndMale()) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addPolygons(stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 1, popup = popup)
  })
  observeEvent (input$gender == "Female", {
    leafletProxy("map", data=lndFemale()) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addPolygons(stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 1, popup = popup2)
  })
}
```

Maybe you have to change part of the code, and use `isolate` somewhere, I don't have the dataset.